# Python & Tkinter - Grid Manager Row Values Causing Overlapping Issues

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My problem is somewhat complex, but I will do my best to describe it.

**The Problem:**

I have an application that uses the Notebook object and builds psuedo-tables on Canvas objects (using Entry objects and the grid manager) inside two of the tabs.  I have some functions set up to remove a row from one tab in the Notebook and dynamically populate it in the other tab with a button press.  However, I am running into a problem due to how the grid manager works - my rows sometimes populates on top of existing rows.  Through some experimentation I believe I found the cause of this.
Suppose I create 3 rows - the grid manager will have packed them using row 1, 2, and 3 when they were generated.  If I decide to move Row 1 from the "Main" tab to the "Other" tab, the widgets in row 1 are destroyed (using the destroy() method) and any widgets in rows below it are visually moved higher; but their grid manager row value hasn't changed.  That fact (the row value thing) is what is creating a problem for me.  To dynamically populate things, I use an array that points to the widget objects so I can references them during runtime and I had previously thought that simply grabbing the length of this array prior to dynamically adding anything, adding 1 to that value, and telling the grid manager to start populating at that "adjusted length value" would be enough to prevent any accidental overlays.  I had not considered that the initial row values assigned are still considered "in use" by the grid manager.

**Example**

1. I have 3 rows as mentioned above, using rows 1, 2, and 3 by the grid manager.
2. I decide to move row 1 to the "Other" tab so all widgets in row 1 are destroyed and all the information is now dynamically populated in the "Other" tab.  Row 2 and 3 in the "Main" tab are shifted up, but (presumably) maintain their initial grid values of 2 and 3.
3. I move to the "Other" tab and decide that moving this row is a mistake, so I click a button that moves it back.
4. A function grabs the length of the pseudo-table array and says "Awesome, 2 items in here.  One more than that is your start value so start populating new widgets at index 3" (row 0 is my header).
   Since widgets that used row 3 in the grid manager still exist, the new widgets are simply placed on top of it.

**Current Workaround**

My current workaround (which is usually a terrible plan) is to simply create a counter that always increases in number whenever a new row is added.  So row 1 would instead be pushed in as row 4.  If I repeated this process, the next row would populate as row 5 (I would still only have 3 rows of widgets though).  This counter is basically reset once the application closes and reopens. Since the largest integer in Python is astronomically large (I think someone provided a number on StackOverflow showing 9 Quintillion), there is no chance that a user will ever hit that number before it simply resets.

**Question to StackOverflow**

It is generally poor form to do these kinds of things and I was wondering if there is a better way to dynamically populate these rows so I don't have to use a counter variable?

Comment: You can call `.grid_size()` on the container to determine the next available column/row numbers; use that row for the row you're adding.

Comment: A few lines of code to create a [mcve] would have been better than this essay. Do your "rows" have columns, or are they each just a single widget like a label or entry widget?

Comment: @jasonharper: Your solution worked brilliantly.  Thank you :-)  After a lot of scouring I also found a PDF reference for Python Tkinter.  Thank you again!